# Language activator or conceptual dictionary for French

Tags: resource-request, vocabulary, dictionary, french

Is there a language activator or conceptual dictionary for French? I haven't been able to find a printed or online one.

More specifically, I am looking for a dictionary that gives related words to a particular word. For example, in the *Reader's Digest Reverse Dictionary*, the entry for "wall" has words such as alcove, niche, grout, etc. These are related words that a thesaurus doesn't give. This type of dictionary would help me a lot in learning vocabulary in a systematic way. Longman (the publisher) calls such a book a Language Activator, but they don't make one for French.

Comment: Apparently it's also called a conceptual dictionary, idealogical dictionary, or *dictionnaire idéologique* en français.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll continue my search.

Comment: @Lambie I have been teaching for 16 years. Yes, these dictionaries are not widely known, but I find them very useful. Feel free to have a look at Longman's Language Activator, it is still in print.
Thanks to Brandin , I found Dictionnaire idéologique by Robertson on archive.org. I think it is an excellent reference book. Have a look.

Comment: Lambie is right about the accepted definition of "reverse dictionary". However @Lambie's comment is irrelevant because the *Reader's Digest Reverse Dictionary* does not fit that definition. What this question is looking for is something similar to the *Reader's Digest Reverse Dictionary* and the *Longman Language Activator* (which was geared specifically at learners of English as a foreign language), but for French. Discussions about whether reverse dictionaries (in the accepted sense of the term) are helpful to language learners are irrelevant and should stop.

Comment: @Tsundoku Did you by chance delete my comment? SE gets weirder by the day. You refer to it and it isn't there. It's not even a Cheshire cat's smile.

Comment: @Lambie Comments about reverse dictionaries were overtaken by events and therefore deleted.

Comment: @Tsundoku Really? Your comment that is less informative than mine stays, and mine that **contained the actual definition on a reverse dictionary gets deleted**. And now, you seem to be telling me what to do again.

Comment: @Lambie since the question is not about reverse dictionaries, the definition of that type of dictionary is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @Tsundoku The original question **was about** reverse dictionaries.  You edited it. And then, you said the term is irrelevant. Again, I find that to be in bad faith. All it does it make me look bad and it also removed the **actual definition** of "reverse dictionary".

Comment: @Lambie The original question was not about reverse dictionaries in the generally accepted sense of that word, and you know that, because you pointed out what "reverse dictionary" means. The *Reader's Digest Reverse Dictionary* is not a reverse dictionary and it was clear from the rest of the question that a reverse dictionary is not what the question is looking for.